# html_nodes returns an empty list

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping the number of newspaper articles containing certain words. For example, the word "Republican" in CA in 1929, from this website:

url = https://www.newspapers.com/search/#query=republican&dr_year=1929-1929&p_place=CA

I want to copy the number of hits (in the example, 23490), and I am using this code:

```
  hits <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('.total-hits') %>% 
    html_text()
```

but html_text() returns an empty list. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you scrape the wrong URL, change it to `https://go.newspapers.com/results.php?query=republican&dr_year=1929-1929&p_place=CA` and change `html_nodes` to `html_node` then your code would work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. Seeing the page source, it seems that you want to target `td`. Then, do some string manipulation and crate the output. I leave the first 10 rows below.

```
read_html("https://go.newspapers.com/results.php?query=republican&dr_year=1929-1929&p_place=CA") %>% 
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "\\n", replacement = "") %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(state = V1, count = V2)

                  state  count
1            California 23,490
2          Pennsylvania 51,697
3              New York 35,428
4               Indiana 23,199
5            New Jersey 22,787
6              Missouri 20,650
7                  Ohio 15,270
8              Illinois 14,920
9                  Iowa 14,676
10            Wisconsin 13,821
```

Another way is the following. I further specified where I wanted to get text. There are two targets. So I used `map_dfc()`. In this way, I directly created a data frame. Then, I did similar jobs. This time, I converted character to numeric.

```
map_dfc(.x = c("td.tn", "td.tar"),
        .f = function(x){
              read_html("https://go.newspapers.com/results.php?query=republican&dr_year=1929-1929&p_place=CA") %>% 
              html_nodes(x) %>% 
              html_text()}
        ) %>% 
rename(state = `...1`, count = `...2`) %>% 
mutate(state = gsub(x = state, pattern = "\\n", replacement = ""),
       count = as.numeric(sub(x = count, pattern = ",", replacement = "")))

   state        count
   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 California   23490
 2 Pennsylvania 51697
 3 New York     35428
 4 Indiana      23199
 5 New Jersey   22787
 6 Missouri     20650
 7 Ohio         15270
 8 Illinois     14920
 9 Iowa         14676
10 Wisconsin    13821
```

Comment: @akrun Long time no speak again. That is a very specific way to get the number! I could not go that further, and decided to get all numbers.